# Photoshop mask / brush

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, brush

I'm not sure where to check up what's wrong with my brush setting or mask setting. I used a mask and regular brush with 100% opacity, 100% hardness, but when I brush on the mask tried to remove the object, the object just keeps showing a shadow, like a light ghost. I've attached screenshots of my brush and the mask image here, could anyone help me with this photoshop setting? Greatly appreciated! [image][image] [image]

Comment: It would appear that either your brush is not set to 100% opacity, or the mask is set to less than 100% density

Comment: ...or you're painting with not 100% black color: make sure you're using an absolute black

Comment: ... or the unwanted pixels are on the layer below?

Comment: ... or you could be applying the mask to the wrong layer.  Perhaps instead add the layer mask to the group if you want to mask all the layers contained within it.

Comment: Also possible that you have a selection active (a channel selection would give you this effect).  Try CTRL+H to see if it's hidden, or CTRL+D to just deselect.